# what is 'facility' in log4net Appender?

Tags: log4net, papertrail-app

can you explain me what is'facility' in the log4net appender config ? This is an example from papertrail guide.

```
<appender name="PaperTrail" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender">
  <facility value="Local6" />
  ...
</appender>
```

What is the Local6 for ? and the value 'Local6' ? I did some google search but still feeling confused about it. And I'm looking best practice to use log4net for papertrail too.

Comment: As per [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_LocalSyslogAppender_SyslogFacility.htm), `Local6` is _"reserved for local use"_. Also in the docs: _"Syslog messages must have a facility and and a severity. The severity is derived from the Level of the logging event. **The facility must be chosen from the set of defined syslog LocalSyslogAppender. SyslogFacility values.** The facilities list is predefined and cannot be extended. "_

Comment: Thanks stuartd. The document is useful. But what is different for I set the facility value to 'Authorization' or 'Local1'? Is that value is an information value only? Will log4net process something for differ values?

Comment: log4net uses the facility to set the priority of the message. [Here's the relevant source code](https://github.com/babaru/log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/RemoteSyslogAppender.cs#L470). But it only writes the value, and doesn't itself treat the message differently. The [SysLog RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424) has more details.